# Multi-variable masking with pandas multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing

I’m having such a hard time masking my data frames the way I need to. My dataframe is for products, where a single product can come in various formats or languages. It looks something like:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import choice

prods = [1234,1234,1234,1234,12344,12344,12344,12344,3462,3462,3462,3462,12314,12314,12314,12314,12857,12857,12857,12857]
formats = choice(['Hrd','Elc','Sft'],size=20)
language = choice(['Eng','Spa','Jpn','Chn','Port','Fnch','Rus'],size=20)
restricted = choice(range(5,9),size=20)
df = pd.DataFrame({'products': prods,'formats':formats,'language': language, 'restricted': restricted})
df['instances'] = df['products'].astype(str) + '-' + df['formats'] + '-' + df['language']
md = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(df['products'],df['instances'])))
df.set_index(md)

df
Out[1]:
                     formats language  products  restricted       instances
1234  1234-Sft-Port      Sft     Port      1234           5   1234-Sft-Port
      1234-Elc-Jpn       Elc      Jpn      1234           7    1234-Elc-Jpn
      1234-Hrd-Jpn       Hrd      Jpn      1234           7    1234-Hrd-Jpn
      1234-Hrd-Chn       Hrd      Chn      1234           5    1234-Hrd-Chn
12344 12344-Sft-Chn      Sft      Chn     12344           5   12344-Sft-Chn
      12344-Hrd-Spa      Hrd      Spa     12344           7   12344-Hrd-Spa
      12344-Elc-Jpn      Elc      Jpn     12344           6   12344-Elc-Jpn
      12344-Sft-Port     Sft     Port     12344           5  12344-Sft-Port
3462  3462-Hrd-Jpn       Hrd      Jpn      3462           5    3462-Hrd-Jpn
      3462-Hrd-Jpn       Hrd      Jpn      3462           7    3462-Hrd-Jpn
      3462-Sft-Port      Sft     Port      3462           6   3462-Sft-Port
      3462-Elc-Jpn       Elc      Jpn      3462           7    3462-Elc-Jpn
12314 12314-Sft-Rus      Sft      Rus     12314           5   12314-Sft-Rus
      12314-Elc-Spa      Elc      Spa     12314           5   12314-Elc-Spa
      12314-Hrd-Port     Hrd     Port     12314           7  12314-Hrd-Port
      12314-Elc-Port     Elc     Port     12314           7  12314-Elc-Port
12857 12857-Elc-Jpn      Elc      Jpn     12857           8   12857-Elc-Jpn
      12857-Elc-Spa      Elc      Spa     12857           5   12857-Elc-Spa
      12857-Hrd-Chn      Hrd      Chn     12857           5   12857-Hrd-Chn
      12857-Sft-Port     Sft     Port     12857           7  12857-Sft-Port
```

How do I mask or index for multiple variables? I want to specify something like "select a product in which an electronic format is in Spanish *and* one of the other formats is a Russian hardcover". I can’t simply mask my data frame like `df[(df['language'] == 'Spa') & (df['format'] == 'Elc')]` because that wouldn't filter for the other formats of that product containing a hardcover.

I’ve resorted to complicated `groupby` lambda functions, but that’s incredibly slow for large data frames (mine is over 200,000 rows):

```
mask = df.groupby('products')
mask.apply(lambda x: 
    'spa' in x['formats'].values and 
    'Hrd' in x[x['language']=='Rus']['formats'].values
    )
```

I’ve investigated `df.query()` and a bunch of other methods/functions, but can’t seem to find a way to interact with my dataframe in the way the products need to be grouped. Is there a better way?

Comment: Can you post your expected output? I'm wondering.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce your exact results because you didn't use a deterministic random seed, but I can index by a union of two intersections using the 'or' operator, `|`:

```
import pandas as pd    
from numpy.random import RandomState
   ...:
   ...: rand = RandomState(4321)
   ...: prods = [1234,1234,1234,1234,12344,12344,12344,12344,3462,3462,3462,3462,12314,1231
   ...: 4,12314,12314,12857,12857,12857,12857]
   ...: formats = rand.choice(['Hrd','Elc','Sft'],size=20)
   ...: language = rand.choice(['Eng','Spa','Jpn','Chn','Port','Fnch','Rus'],size=20)
   ...: restricted = rand.choice(range(5,9),size=20)
   ...: df = pd.DataFrame({'products': prods,'formats':formats,'language': language, 'restr
   ...: icted': restricted})
   ...: df['instances'] = df['products'].astype(str) + '-' + df['formats'] + '-' + df['lang
   ...: uage']
   ...: md = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(zip(df['products'],df['instances'])))
   ...: df2 = df.set_index(md)
   ...: df2
   ...:
   ...:
Out[1]:
                      products formats language  restricted       instances
1234  1234-Elc-Spa        1234     Elc      Spa           8    1234-Elc-Spa
      1234-Sft-Rus        1234     Sft      Rus           8    1234-Sft-Rus
      1234-Hrd-Spa        1234     Hrd      Spa           7    1234-Hrd-Spa
      1234-Sft-Spa        1234     Sft      Spa           7    1234-Sft-Spa
12344 12344-Hrd-Spa      12344     Hrd      Spa           8   12344-Hrd-Spa
      12344-Sft-Rus      12344     Sft      Rus           5   12344-Sft-Rus
      12344-Elc-Fnch     12344     Elc     Fnch           7  12344-Elc-Fnch
      12344-Elc-Spa      12344     Elc      Spa           6   12344-Elc-Spa
3462  3462-Elc-Fnch       3462     Elc     Fnch           8   3462-Elc-Fnch
      3462-Sft-Jpn        3462     Sft      Jpn           6    3462-Sft-Jpn
      3462-Hrd-Port       3462     Hrd     Port           6   3462-Hrd-Port
      3462-Sft-Eng        3462     Sft      Eng           8    3462-Sft-Eng
12314 12314-Elc-Spa      12314     Elc      Spa           7   12314-Elc-Spa
      12314-Hrd-Spa      12314     Hrd      Spa           7   12314-Hrd-Spa
      12314-Elc-Fnch     12314     Elc     Fnch           7  12314-Elc-Fnch
      12314-Hrd-Port     12314     Hrd     Port           5  12314-Hrd-Port
12857 12857-Hrd-Port     12857     Hrd     Port           7  12857-Hrd-Port
      12857-Sft-Rus      12857     Sft      Rus           5   12857-Sft-Rus
      12857-Elc-Rus      12857     Elc      Rus           6   12857-Elc-Rus
      12857-Elc-Jpn      12857     Elc      Jpn           8   12857-Elc-Jpn
```

There is surely a more elegant solution (or a shorter hack like concatenating the strings in `products` and `formats` and filtering on the result) but this works:

```
filter_df = df2[((df2.formats == 'Elc') & (df2.language == 'Spa')) | ((df2.formats == 'Sft') & (df2.language == 'Rus'))]
filter_groups = filter_df.groupby(level=0)['products'].count()
filter_index = filter_groups[filter_groups > 1].index
df3 = df2[df2.index.get_level_values(0).isin(filter_index)]

Out[3]:
                      products formats language  restricted       instances
1234  1234-Elc-Spa        1234     Elc      Spa           8    1234-Elc-Spa
      1234-Sft-Rus        1234     Sft      Rus           8    1234-Sft-Rus
      1234-Hrd-Spa        1234     Hrd      Spa           7    1234-Hrd-Spa
      1234-Sft-Spa        1234     Sft      Spa           7    1234-Sft-Spa
12344 12344-Hrd-Spa      12344     Hrd      Spa           8   12344-Hrd-Spa
      12344-Sft-Rus      12344     Sft      Rus           5   12344-Sft-Rus
      12344-Elc-Fnch     12344     Elc     Fnch           7  12344-Elc-Fnch
      12344-Elc-Spa      12344     Elc      Spa           6   12344-Elc-Spa
```

You had asked to select products; if you want to narrow down to only those instances of a product that match you would need to filter again on these results.